# problema com unnest_tokens()

Tags: r, text

Sou Linguista, trabalho com mineração de textos e estou tentando importar um romance (200 páginas de texto escrito linearmente com quebras de linha) para análise no R. Diversos erros ocorrem.

Primeiro tentei:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
estrela <- readLines("estrela.txt")
estrela.tidy <- estrela %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

Depois tentei:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
estrela <- read_file("estrela.txt")
estrela.tidy <- estrela %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

O Resultado que tenho é em ambos os casos:

```
Error in UseMethod("unnest_tokens_"): no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Estou fazendo algo errado? Há alguma forma mais simples de se importar um texto para se trabalhar com **tidytext**?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa trasnformar o seu texto em `data.frame`:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
estrela <- "texto stackoverflow português"
estrela <- data.frame(text = estrela, stringsAsFactors = F)
estrela.tidy <- estrela %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

Resultado:

```
             word
1           texto
1.1 stackoverflow
1.2     português
```

Esse erro `Error in UseMethod("unnest_tokens_"): no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class "character"` significa que `estrela` é de classe `character` e esta classe não é aceitável para a função `unnest_tokens`. Observe que após transfomar `estrela` em `data.frame`, temos o seguinte:

```
estrela <- data.frame(text = estrela, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

No console:

```
> class(estrela)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Na documentação da função `unnest_tokens` (`?unnest_tokens` no console):

> Arguments
>
> `tbl`  A data frame

Comment: Muito obrigado!